# PHP statement is right?

Tags: php, session-variables

Does my code is right?

```
<?php 
if(session_id() == '') {
     session_start();
} 
if($_SESSION["logged"]== true && isset($_SESSION["userlogged"]))  {
    header('Location: page.php');
} 

?>
```

what I need to fix because I am getting this error:

> Undefined index: logged

Comment: `$_SESSION["logged"]` does not exist, where is it set?

Comment: It's set when user successful login on the page

Comment: ^ Please show this.

Comment: clarly not, or you would not get the error

Comment: user is not logged in the page, it gets the error on login page before user is logged

Comment: So the variable doesn't get set, which explains your error.

Comment: I tried to fix but it gives me `sintax error` someone could give me a safe example how to check `isset` inside the if condition? something like use 3 conditions on the if

Answer (score 1):

for debugging, you might want to update your code from:

```
if($_SESSION["logged"]== true && isset($_SESSION["userlogged"]))  {
    header('Location: page.php');
}
```

to the following:

```
//isset() checks whether the key exists.
if(isset($_SESSION["logged"]) && $_SESSION["logged"]== true && isset($_SESSION["userlogged"]))  {
    header('Location: page.php');
} else {
    //just for debugging purpose, remove it before pushing it to production.
    echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);die();
}
```